# How to integrate a Vue project with Velocity.js , any examples?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, velocity.js

Currently I am trying to integrate Projects from CodePen that use Velocity.js and I am unable to integrate them in my project. 
In the main.js file I import velocity from 'velocity-animate'

Any examples out there?

Comment: could you share the code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/idhuG 
This is one that I tried to import - to no avail

Comment: https://codepen.io/StephenScaff/pen/dWmJxj
This is another one that I want to do

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks
or even the example on the website - I tried doing it that way and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it in the following way

```
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate'

mounted(){
..
  Velocity($element,{property: value});
..
}
```

this in the view that you want to implement.